# Using Post to access SQL database from Python through PHP

Tags: php, python, mysql, web-services

I have a Python plugin with which I need to connect to a remote MySQL server. This plugin will be on multiple production devices and the source is open so I don't want database information stored in there. So I am trying to use a PHP web service to get the data, and am using post requests to access it. When the python script runs it gives an error and says No JSON object could be decoded.

Here's the PHP code (SQL Connection credentials redacted):

```
$con = mysqli_connect('url', 'user', 'pass', 'db') or die('Connection Failed');

$mac = $_POST['mac'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT 1 FROM `Boxes` WHERE `MAC` = '$mac'");
$rows = $result->num_rows;
if ($rows != 0) {
    $response['Result'] = "Registered";
} else {
    $response['Result'] = "Not Registered";
}

json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($con);
```

And here is the Python Code:

```
params = {'mac': mac}
r = requests.post("http://lastboxusa.com/php/LCheckReg.php", data=params)
data = r.json()
return data['Result'] == "Registered"
```

Lastly, here's the full stack trace:

```
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
Error Contents: No JSON object could be decoded
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ncben\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\service.lastboxmanagement\addon.py", line 94, in <module> if checkreg(mac):
File "C:\Users\ncben\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\service.lastboxmanagement\addon.py", line 35, in checkreg data = r.json()
File "C:\Users\ncben\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\script.module.requests\lib\requests\models.py", line 850, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\system\python\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\system\python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\system\python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

I'm very new to PHP so (I hope) it's probably some silly error in my PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple things, don't do this `"SELECT 1 FROM \`Boxes\` WHERE \`MAC\` = '$mac'"`, you need to bind parameters on `$mac` since it's user-manipulated/manipulatable. Second, add a value that you know that will generate results on the php page. Make sure that works first. Last, you need to `echo json_encode($response);` not just `json_encode($response);`

Comment: I had previously had the echo there but it didn't change anything. Turns out the problem was that I mistyped the password... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The `json_encode($response);` line should be `echo json_encode($response);`

But more importantly, the password should be typed correctly.